# Create column with year name if all following years meet condition

Tags: pandas, loops

I have the following dataset

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'UID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
    'Year': [2015, 2016, 2017, 2014, 2015, 2017, 2014, 2015, 2016],
    'Good?': [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
})
```

for each UID, I am trying to figure out what is the first Year value whose respective 'Good?' value is 1 and also whose following Year values meet the condition 'Good?' as 1. In case the condition is not met, I would like to assign the value as 2017.

I seem to have some problems with the indexing as it throws a 'KeyError: #####' - I guess there are cases where I have only one year value and that is throwing an error. this is what I got so far.

```
# Group the DataFrame by UID
groups = df.groupby('UID')

# Initialize an empty list to store the results
results = []

# Loop over each UID group
for uid, group in groups:
    # Find the first index with a Good value of 1
    first_good_index = group[group['Good?'] == 1].index[0]
    print(first_good_index)
    
    # Check if all following years have a Good value of 1
    if (group.loc[first_good_index+1:, 'Good?'] == 1).all():
        # If so, append the UID and the year of the first good row to the results list
        results.append((uid, group.loc[first_good_index, 'Year']))
    else:
        results.append((uid, 2017))

    
# Create a DataFrame from the results
results_df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['UID', 'First Good Year'])

# Print the results
print(results_df)
```

these are the expected results

```
results_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'UID': [1, 2, 3],
    'First Good Year': [2016, 2017, 2017],
})

results_df
```

Comment: can you post the final expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#test 1 values
m = df['Good?'].eq(1)

#test if all values after first 1 is not 1
mask = m.groupby(df['UID']).cummax() & ~m

#filter UIDs with only 1 in Good column
df1 = df[~df['UID'].isin(df.loc[mask, 'UID']) & m]
print (df1)
   UID  Year  Good?
1    1  2016      1
2    1  2017      1
5    2  2017      1

#get first `IUD` wth append missing `UID` filled by 2017
out = (df1.drop_duplicates('UID')
          .set_index('UID')['Year']
          .reindex(df['UID'].unique(), fill_value=2017)
          .reset_index())
print (out)
   UID  Year
0    1  2016
1    2  2017
2    3  2017
```

Comment: this is great - you did a better job than chatgpt :)

Comment: Sorry, I think the code is not delivering the expected results and I must have been unclear: I am looking for the first good year - meaning the first year where Good? ==1 that is followed by all years where Good?==1. This does not have to be the first year available for each TCUID, it can be a later year.

Comment: @FilippoSebastio - Can you change data for see how not working this solution like you need?